# Refresh Bound Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh

I have seen lots of examples on how to do this and I can do it but it displays the wrong data set.  My issue is that I have a switch board and pass a paramater to another form using this code:

```
        public void LoadCaseNumberKey(String CaseNumberKey)
    {
        propertyInformationTableAdapter1.FillByCaseNumberKey(newCityCollectionDataSet.PropertyInformation, CaseNumberKey);
        muniLiensTableAdapter.FillByCaseNumberKey(newCityCollectionDataSet.MuniLiens, CaseNumberKey);
        documentsTableAdapter.FillByCaseNumberKey(newCityCollectionDataSet.Documents, CaseNumberKey);
    }
```

So if I do choose to use one of the many ideas in this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/18a9762e-ac67-48a7-a372-55307fe344f3   I get the wrong data as it refreshes the table adapter with the entire dataset.

The code I use to add a record is as follows:

```
         private void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

         MuniLien newlien = new MuniLien();
         newlien.CaseNumberKey = caseNumberKeyTextBox.Text;
         db.MuniLiens.InsertOnSubmit(newlien);
         db.SubmitChanges();

         this.muniLiensDataGridView.EndEdit();
         this.muniLiensDataGridView.Refresh();


     }
```

What would be the best way to refresh the datagridview?   This is the code that refreshes it but with the entire dataset as opposed to the correct set:

```
 this.muniLiensTableAdapter.Fill(this.CityDataSet.muniLiens);
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just  call again your method of loading data on datagridview.

e.g:

```
private void LoadCaseNumberKey(String CaseNumberKey)
{//do your stuff loading to datagrid }


        private void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {          DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();         
    MuniLien newlien = new MuniLien();
    newlien.CaseNumberKey = caseNumberKeyTextBox.Text;

    db.MuniLiens.InsertOnSubmit(newlien);
    db.SubmitChanges();  
    this.muniLiensDataGridView.EndEdit(); 
    this.muniLiensDataGridView.Refresh();      

    // add this if it is the way you bind datagrid -->> LoadCaseNumberKey(String CaseNumberKey)
    or
    //LoadData();

}
```

Regards

Comment: When I try to call my method again it does not like the parameter.  For instance if I use LoadCaseNumberKey(String CaseNumberKey) it underlines "String CaseNUmberKey" in red.  How do I fix that problem?

Comment: Nevermind I had to do this LoadCaseNumberKey(newlien.CaseNumberKey)